# Find column values that are present for multiple months in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by, pandas-groupby

how to filter the ids which are existed into multiple months with DateTime in Pandas, Python 3

```
DateTime             ID                                         
2011-01-30 08:00:59 367341093   
2011-01-30 08:03:00 367341093   
2011-02-01 08:03:59 367341093
2011-02-01 08:05:00 367341093
2011-03-12 08:05:00 367341093
2011-03-12 08:05:00 367341093
2011-01-15 08:05:00 367341034
2011-01-15 08:05:00 367341034
2011-01-15 08:05:00 367341012
2011-01-15 08:05:00 367341012
2011-01-15 08:05:00 367341012
2011-02-23 08:05:00 367341045
2011-02-23 08:05:00 367341045
2011-03-01 08:05:00 367341045
```

result should be two ids which are in multiple months 1,2 and 3

```
result = [367341045, 367341093]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `groupby` and `nunique`:

```
u = df['DateTime'].dt.month.groupby(df.ID).nunique()
u

ID
367341012    1
367341034    1
367341045    2
367341093    3
Name: DateTime, dtype: int64

u.index[u > 1]
# Int64Index([367341045, 367341093], dtype='int64', name='ID')
```